# Batch how to read part of a folder name from directory

Tags: file, batch-file, directory

Morning,

Id like to read all folder names from a directory but then extract part of this name to a text file.

E.g.

Folder \users\music has these folders within:
Tes125559-blah345534
tes125558-blah235235

Id like to extract 3 characters in until the -, so for Tes125559-blah345534 im after just the 125559 to be put into a text file.

Its always 3 chars in then a 6 digit numeric value that needs grabbing

Any help is very appreciated, so far I only read the directory:

dir /b > file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do the trick:

```
@echo off
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        if exist file.txt del file.txt
        for /d %%a in (*) do (
                set DIR=%%a
                echo !DIR:~3,6!>>file.txt
        )
```

The `for` loop iterates over all directories (in the current directory).  For each one, it stores the directory name in `DIR` and then uses a "sub-string" syntax to extract six characters starting at the fourth (the `3` is because it counts from zero -- see `SET /?` for more information).

The use of `!` around this construct (and `enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of the script) is because the normal way of referring to environment variables (with `%`) would not re-evaluate the value of `%DIR%` each time around the `for` loop (see `cmd /?` for more details).

Because each directory is appended to the `file.txt`, we delete it before we start (if it exists).

Comment: Perfect! Works a treat. This is 100% what I was after. Thankyou so much!